# OpenL tablets Rules with many condition memory issue

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In my organisation we have rules built in Openl tablets with 20 + column conditions in few of them. This consumes all of the java heap size and then application hangs . Any suggestion what to do ?

Manual garbage collection using System.gc() , but didn't work

Source code available from OpenL tablets

https://github.com/openl-tablets/openl-tablets/releases/tag/release-5.22.1/

Garbage collection should be more efficient and not consume all the memory when more conditions are added to condition columns.

Anything above 20 columns starts consuming additional memory , every edit , upload add to the previous memory utilization.

We have tried on a 32 GB linux server with 24 GB java heap size but doesn't 
solve the problem

Comment: As far as I know, System.gc() won't trigger garbage collector right way.

Answer (score 1):

Problem your are describing is memory leak (not the Garbage collector problem).

For some reason you have a large number of object occupying in your heap which could not be recycled by GC due to being reachable in object graph.

> Anything above 20 columns starts consuming additional memory , every edit , upload add to the previous memory utilization.

That means every edit, upload, etc leaks some memory.

You need to find cause of memory leak using tool for heap dump analysis. I can suggests free JVisualVM and Eclipse MAT.

I would recommend to to take two heap dumps:

- first once application is restarted
- second after few edits, upload (avoid filling whole memory, working with 20GiB heap dump is a pain)

In heap dump analysis tools you can compare dumps and find which kind of objects are being leaked. Same tool would also allow you trace a paths from leaked object instances to GC root.